# How to fix type error while concatenating two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am new to Python and I am writing a simple program. When I execute the code using python 3.7, it gives me the below error:

> Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Both sublist1 and sublist2 are list type but still it is not getting concatenated.

```
MyList = list(range(1,51))
sublist1 = MyList[-26:-29:-1]
sublist1 = sublist1.reverse()
sublist2 = MyList[25:27:1]
print(sublist1 + sublist2)
```

Comment: No, you assign `None` to `sublist1` here: `sublist1 = sublist1.reverse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works.  See explanation following it for why:

```
MyList = list(range(1,51))
sublist1 = MyList[-26:-29:-1]
sublist1.reverse()
sublist2 = MyList[25:27:1]
print(sublist1 + sublist2)  ## [23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

Built-in `reverse()` method reverses the contents of the list object in-place. Reversing the list in-place means it won’t create a new list. Instead, it directly modifies the original list object.  `reverse()` returns None, but modifies the original list object. See below for why it was deliberately done this way:

> The reverse() method modifies the sequence in place for economy of
>   space when reversing a large sequence. To remind users that it
>   operates by side effect, it does not return the reversed sequence.
>   (Source: [Python 3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list))

if you must assign it to something, you need to do:
`sublist3 = list(reversed(sublist1))`
or
`sublist3 = sublist1[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` reverses the list in-place, so you just needed to reverse and not assign back:

```
sublist1.reverse()
```

The error you get clearly tells that you are trying to concatenate a `None` type to a `list` type.

```
sublist1 = sublist1.reverse()
```

This is going to assign a `None` to `sublist1` as the reverse operation does not return anything.